# Logout control not working

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have login/logout links in the main layout of my application, in the manner described by David Leedy in this video: http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/03/09/notesin9-049-xpages-login-and-logout/

Everything works fine, except for the logout link. The code for the link is:

`facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath() + "?Logout&redirectTo=" + facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath()`

When it is clicked, then I get logged out and returned to the homepage, which is fine. But then if I refresh, or click onto another page, I am immediately logged back in without a password prompt. Is this because there is a session saved on the server which is not being cleared? How can I change this so that after logging out, someone would have to go through the full login process again before being logged in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends if your server is setup to use basic or session based authentication. There is no logout mechanism for basic authentication, you are logged out when you close the browser.

The above code will only work for session based which is configured on your domino server through domino admin.

here are some instructions:
http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_admin.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/1e4058257e426e5e8525706f0065d97a?OpenDocument