# If more than one Internet Explorer opens, how to prompt the user to login again after they have been logged out the application?

Tags: xpages

I have a xpage application that requires the user to login using the lotus notes user and related internet password.

The default browser to open the application is Internet Explorer.

In the application, I have a logout button and it looks like this

```
<xp:button value="Logout" id="button1">             
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script>
            <xp:executeClientScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var logout=window.confirm ("Do you want to logout this application?");
                    if (logout==true)
                    {
                        //close the browser
                        window.close()
                    }
                ]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeClientScript>
        </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

I notice that if I open more that one Internet Explorer, and when I close one browser and open the browser again to access the application.
The application does not prompt me to login and seems remember my session.

Maybe my description is confusing, please imagine the following scenario

1. I open Internet Explorer and type the url to access the application. (please note this is the first browser)
2. The browser will ask me to input the correct username and password to login.
3. I am able to access to the application.
4. I open another Internet Explorer and this browser is not for the application, it uses for other purpose. (the second browser)
5. At this moment, I opened two Internet Explorer browsers in total.
6. Suppose I complete the task in the application, I click the logout button, it prompts "Do you want to logout this application?", I click "Yes".
7. The browser closes the application.(please note I close the first browser)
8. The second browser is still open.
9. At this moment, only one Internet Explorer browser is opened.
10. Suddenly I have another task to do in the application, so I open the Internet Explorer again and type the url.
11. However this time, the browser does not requires me to login, it opens the application directly.

The browser seems remember my login information because it opens the application without login.

So far as I know when I close a browser, it will not remember any information. Therefore I don't understand why this happen as I use window.close to close the browser.

I expect when I logout or close the application in the browser, it will prompt me to login if I need to access the application.

So if more than one Internet Explorer opens, how to prompt the user to login again after they have been logged out the application?

Is it something wrong in my log out button?

Grateful for your advice please. Thank you very much.

Comment: As far as I know, all open IE windows share their session information. They are not independent browsers, like when you open IE and FF side by side.

Comment: This question should clear your doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720262/logout-control-not-working/10721030

Answer (score 0):

Your "logout" button does not actually log the user out - it just closes the window.

You need to do a proper logout by sending the server the `?logout` command (assuming you use session based authentication). You should also consider making sure that the XPages session is terminated properly by clearing sessionScope variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this code `window.open('http://server/database.nsf?Logout','_self');`. When I click the button and choose to logout, it will redirect me to the company's internal url. I search on the internet and find the reason is the server setting. Unfortunately, I don't have the right to change server setting. So I discussed with the server administrator about this issue. He said in the server setting, the Home URL is already mapped to the company's internal url. Therefore no matter which application, if it uses ?Logout, it will automatically redirect to the mapped url.

Comment: I have an idea and it is I ask the administrator to create another new Home URL, e.g. `database.nsf/application.xsp?Open`, if the user is using my application, the logout button will redirect to the new Home URL. If the user is using other application, the logout button will redirect to the original Home URL (company's internal URL). However how can I know the user is using my application, and logout will redirect to the specify Home URL?

Comment: You can use the RedirectTo URL parameter. So use this as the URL in the button: ?logout&redirectTo=/path/database.nsf/application.xsp

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again. I used the RedirectTo URL parameter but when I click the logout button, it still redirect to the company's internal url. Would you have a look for the code and let me know my mistake please. Thank you very much. `window.open('http://servername/database.nsf?Logout&redirectTo=http://servername/database.nsf/application.xsp' ,'_self');`

Comment: You need to remove the http part from the redirectTo parameter

Comment: If I remove http://, so the code will look like this `window.open('http://servername/database.nsf?Logout&redirectT‌​o=servername/‌​database.nsf/applica‌​tion.xsp' ,'_self');`. But when I click the button, the Internet Explorer says The webpage cannot be found. At same time I notice the url on browser is look like this `http://servername/database.nsf?logout&redirectTo=servername/database.nsf/application.xsp`. I copy this part `servername/database.nsf/application.xsp` and paste to the new browser, it can open the page properly.

Comment: I tried to use a variable for servername/database.nsf/application.xsp and then in redirectTo to call the variable. `var url = "servername/database.nsf/application.xsp";  window.open('http://servername/database.nsf?Logout&redirectT‌​‌​o='+url ,'_self');`But the Internet Explorer still says the webpage cannot be found.

Comment: Remove server name. You just need the path to the nsf

Comment: So the code will look like this? `window.open('http://servername/database.nsf?Logout&redirectT‌​‌​o=dat‌​abase.nsf/applica‌​t‌​ion.xsp' ,'_self');` However, it redirects me to the company's internal url, not the url that I specify in the button